# Duplicate identifier 'EventEmitter'

Tags: angular, npm, components, angular8, node-modules

I am facing this problem

> (error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'EventEmitter'.)

and

> (error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'Output'.).

after including this

```
@Input() public parentData; name;
@Output() public childEvent = new EventEmitter();
```

the error comes in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You usually get that error when you have imported them multiple times

here is a stackblitz showing same error on hover because of duplicate imports
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pz7n2f